# How to set a priority of retrofit requests

Tags: java, android, request, android-viewpager, retrofit

I have `ViewPager` and in this ViewPager there are 4 fragments. Sorry but I can't to add a code, because that would be very big. Each of my fragments on create does asynchronous retrofit request to server. I have `access_token` and `refresh_token` too. So when my `access_token` expires I need to do a call using `refresh_token` to update my `access_token`. So when I launch my application it opens viewPager with my 4 fragments doing asynchronous requests. That means 4 requests at a time. And when my access_token is expired and I'm launching my app, all the fragments try to update the access token using refresh token. Turns out that one fragment updates the access_token (after the update refresh_token changes) other fragments try to update the token too, but I'm getting 401 because 1 fragment already updated the token and other fragments try to update the access_token using  old refresh token.

Here is the example of one request.

```
Call<ResponseBody> getChatImageCall = apiClient.getImages(cutMessage, CHAT_IMAGE_TYPE);
getChatImageCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    messagesAdapter.addToStart(MessagesFixtures.getImageBytesMessage(response.body().bytes(), id), true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Here is the token update request part

```
public class RefreshToken {

Context context;
TokenUpdaterCallback tokenUpdaterCallback;
ApiClient apiClient = ApiClient.getInstance();

public RefreshToken(Context context, TokenUpdaterCallback tokenUpdaterCallback) {
    this.context = context;
    this.tokenUpdaterCallback = tokenUpdaterCallback;
}

public void updateToken() {

    //Perform this call if access token is expired

    SupportObjToken supportObjToken = new SupportObjToken();

    supportObjToken.setGrantType("refresh_token");
    supportObjToken.setClientId(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getClientId());
    supportObjToken.setClientSecret(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getClientSecret());
    supportObjToken.setRefreshToken(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getRefreshToken());

    Call<RefreshTokenActivation> newToken = apiClient.newToken(supportObjToken);
    newToken.enqueue(new Callback<RefreshTokenActivation>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RefreshTokenActivation> call, Response<RefreshTokenActivation> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String newAccessToken = response.body().getAccessToken();
                String newRefreshToken = response.body().getRefreshToken();

                UserData userData = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData();
                SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().removeUser();
                userData.setAccessToken(newAccessToken);
                userData.setRefreshToken(newRefreshToken);
                SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().setUser(userData);

                tokenUpdaterCallback.updateToken();
            } else {
                if (response.code() == 401) {

                    //Perform this call if refresh token is expired

                    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
                    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
                    mainActivity.logOut();
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "You logged on other hardware", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RefreshTokenActivation> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Response is not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}

tokenUpdaterCallback is a simple interface with updateToken() method. So you don't need this.
```

Comment: From where are you calling that `request_token` API can you please share that code

Comment: Wait I'll add the token update code part

Comment: From where you calling `updateToken` method and what error you are getting when your `access_token` is expired

Comment: When I'm doing request from fragment and get 401, I'm call this refresh token class. The update token method is when I'm updating my token I'm doing request from fragment one more time, else when it gets 401 and updates then nothing happens)

Comment: Okay can you add a flag in your `RefreshToken` class , for example `requesting_token` set it true when you entering the updatetoken method. and set it false when your api call is done with success/failure. and when calling the updateToken api check for that variable

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RefreshToken {

    Context context;
    TokenUpdaterCallback tokenUpdaterCallback;
    ApiClient apiClient = ApiClient.getInstance();
    boolean isLoading = false;

    public RefreshToken(Context context, TokenUpdaterCallback tokenUpdaterCallback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.tokenUpdaterCallback = tokenUpdaterCallback;
    }

    public void updateToken() {
        if (!isLoading) {
            isLoading = true;
            //Perform this call if access token is expired

            SupportObjToken supportObjToken = new SupportObjToken();

            supportObjToken.setGrantType("refresh_token");
            supportObjToken.setClientId(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getClientId());
            supportObjToken.setClientSecret(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getClientSecret());
            supportObjToken.setRefreshToken(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getRefreshToken());

            Call<RefreshTokenActivation> newToken = apiClient.newToken(supportObjToken);
            newToken.enqueue(new Callback<RefreshTokenActivation>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<RefreshTokenActivation> call, Response<RefreshTokenActivation> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String newAccessToken = response.body().getAccessToken();
                        String newRefreshToken = response.body().getRefreshToken();

                        UserData userData = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData();
                        SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().removeUser();
                        userData.setAccessToken(newAccessToken);
                        userData.setRefreshToken(newRefreshToken);
                        SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().setUser(userData);

                        tokenUpdaterCallback.updateToken();
                    } else {
                        if (response.code() == 401) {

                            //Perform this call if refresh token is expired

                            Activity activity = (Activity) context;
                            MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
                            mainActivity.logOut();
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "You logged on other hardware", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        isLoading = false;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RefreshTokenActivation> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Response is not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isLoading = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```